# "Re-attaching" an LVM volume/group

Tags: linux, lvm, lvm2

I created an image and used it to create a logical volume like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=LVM.img bs=1024 count=$((64*1024))
sudo losetup --find --partscan LVM.img
sudo pvcreate /dev/loop0
sudo vgcreate vg00 /dev/loop0
sudo lvcreate -L 4 vg00 -n lv00
```

I then removed/deactivated/unmounted/detached/whatever both the logical volume and the volume group:

```
sudo lvchange -an /dev/vg00/lv00
sudo vgchange -an /dev/vg00
```

Okay. Now if I want to get it such that these are present in `/dev` again (I don't know what word to use)? What's more, how come I have not come across a guide stating how to "re-attach" volume groups and logical volumes?

Answer (score 0):

By using lvchange/vgchange -an you deactivate lvm and vg.

For activate it again please do:

```
root@uml:~# lvchange -an /dev/vg00/lv00
root@uml:~# vgchange -an /dev/vg00
  0 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg00" now active
root@uml:~# lvscan |grep vg00
  inactive          '/dev/vg00/lv00' [4,00 MiB] inherit
root@uml:~# vgchange -ay /dev/vg00
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg00" now active
root@uml:~# lvchange -ay /dev/vg00
root@uml:~# lvscan |grep vg00
 ACTIVE            '/dev/vg00/lv00' [4,00 MiB] inherit
```

Comment: How does it know to associate `vg00` with `/dev/loop0`?

Comment: using pvscan - if loop0 is active and attached - it will be scaned and can be activated using vgchange. List of devices to be scanned is in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf - by default everything in /dev/ is scanned. If you would like to exclude some devices (for example loops - add there line like: filter = [ "a/loop/", "r/.*/" ]